# Not getting current location even if Location Services are enabled

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play-store, google-maps, location-services

Device: Samsung mobile phone
Android: 4.0.3

My Location Services are enabled, but I am not getting the current location. When I restart the phone, it works.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: So is it working now or does it stop working after a while and only a restart fixes it? And what app aren't you getting the location in? I've had a similar problem when developing an app (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594932/network-provider-not-providing-updated-locations) but there isn't any known fix for the issue.

Comment: No, I cant able to found out the fix, can you have any solution regarding this

Comment: Nope I never did find a solution, neither did anyone else as far as I know, I just restart the phone occasionally if it stops working. Is it Google Maps that it isn't working in though? Do you have the latest version? I've never seen that problem on there.

Comment: so what's the the alternate way you are using for this fix, because i am getting this issue in several Samsung devices.