# Location services not working after a few days

Tags: location-services

The funny thing is that when this happens, Google Maps and Google Earth can still find my location, but all other apps, such as Facebook, Chrome, and even the Samsung Weather Widget, can't find my location. Rebooting the phone again fixes the issue, but then it comes back after a few days. This leads me to think that it's a software problem instead of a hardware problem; why else would Google Maps and Earth be able to find my location but other apps can't, and that rebooting solves the problem for a few days?

Does anyone else have the same problem? I don't exactly know when it started happening, but it's a small bother.

Comment: Could you give a few more details on your device and Android version? If it's already 4.3, the Google apps could be using a "different source" (IMHO there was some "un-disable-able" background location service introduced)...

Comment: It's Happening from Android 2.2 and above versions(Samsung,Sony Ericsson,MicroMax....)

Comment: Similar: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50819/not-getting-current-location-even-if-location-services-are-enabled

Comment: And this seems to be a known issue, I've experienced it when developing an app that used location services. Question on SO about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594932/network-provider-not-providing-updated-locations

Comment: I already used google play services but its not working for me. If u have any sample code pls send me. Every device working for 4 or 5 days continously.